# Ruby on Rails Namespacing and Nested Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I'm learning Ruby and Rails and trying to figure out the most correct path to go for my scenario regarding possibly namespacing as well as routing.

Say I have a 'Zoo' model as well as 'Species' model.  I also need a relationship between them to tell what Species are in what Zoos (a Zoo has many Species, which will also have their own properties such as qty, location, etc)

I would like my routes to be like:

```
/zoo
/zoo/:id
...
/zoo/:zoo_id/species/
/zoo/:zoo_id/species/:id
...
/species
/species/:id
```

I have tried messing with modules, namespaces, route scopes, etc.  I can't seem to get it how I'd like and think there has to be a better/natural way to do this.  The problem is mainly due to the fact that I have a species model as well as a species model of zoo (I've tried namespacing to Zoo and creating a Zoo::Zoo and Zoo::Species classes, creating a ZooSpecies class, and adjusting routes for those scenarios, etc)

From an organizational standpoint, it would be great to be able to have a Zoo class as well as a Zoo namespace, to have Zoo::Species and such, but that is not possible.

What is the proper way to organize something like this?

**Update:  My current setup...**

```
Zoo Module
Zoo::Zoo Class
Zoo::Species Class
Species Class
```

Routes:

```
resources :zoos, path: 'zoos' do
  resources :zoo_species, path: 'species', as: 'species', controller: 'zoo/species'
end
```

And a `Zoo` controller and a `Zoo::Species` controller.  I feel like I'm getting closer to the desired result, but fighting against the framework more than I think I should.  Still running into some issues properly setting up the relationships and paths, having to specify a lot of config values

Comment: Why would you want both `/zoo/:zoo_id/species/:id` and `/species/:id`?

Comment: Wouldn't the relationship between Zoo and Species be M:M?

Comment: @tybro0103 - I want both routes so I can show the species in general (eg: this page is about zebras in general) and information about a species that is specifically at a zoo (eg:  this is now many zebras this zoo has, where they are, etc).  And yes, it is many to many through the association.  My problem is mainly due to the fact that I have 'Species' in general, as well as 'ZooSpecies', and then working out the routing to be friendly after that.  So I'm not sure the best way to organize based on that fact... would Species namespaced under Zoo be best?  Or a ZooSpecies class then fix routing?

Answer (score 0):

Try using shallow nesting:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

In your case:

```
resources :zoos
  resources :species, shallow :true
```

Answer (score 0):

To nest resources:

```
resources :zoos do # /zoos(/:id)
  resources :species # /zoos/:zoo_id/species(/:species_id)
end
```

To namespace:

```
namespace :zoo do
  resources :posts # /zoo/posts(/:id)
end
```

If you create that namespace, the you'll need to create app/controllers/zoo/posts_controller.rb with class definition:

```
class Zoo::PostsController < ApplicationController
  # ...
end
```

Note: nested resources and namespaces are two different things. The Rails guide on routing is very readable - which you should definitely do: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: side note: `"species".singularize == "species".pluralize` evals to true... Rails is cool ;)

Comment: The issue with your first nested resource example is that I have a mode species, as well as my relationship, which I called ZooSpecies initially and now is Zoo::Species.  I'll update my question with my updated details of how I have it setup now

Comment: Oddly enough I did have "specy" in my routes at one point.  I've messed around with it enough it has gone away by now, not sure how I ended up there.  I did also add it as a reflection, otherwise it was generating models as specy... strange.

Comment: you might want to checkout the `through` option on `has_many`